# How to use the redux store inside the library module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

We have a large react project with different functionalities. We are using redux to maintain the state across the whole project. But as we kept adding new functionalities, it became very complex to manage the project. So, we moved each functionality to a separate library module and added the library module inside the root project. But now the problem, I am not able to access the store inside the library module.

Below is the error I got when accessing the store inside the library module.

```
Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(i)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(i)".
```

To reproduce the error, I have created a simple TODO application in stackblitz. Here is the URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-brmydx?file=README.md. In this project, I have created a module called **component-library** and published it and used it in the root project. And I have moved the component named **FilterLink**, which uses redux state and used it in the **footer** component in the components package in the root folder.

Is there any way to use the redux store inside the library modules?

Answer (score 0):

#### `react-redux` versions must match between library and app

The design pattern that you are using here is fundamentally sound.  A component in your library should be able to use `connect` (or `useDispatch` or `useSelector`) without issues, even though the `store` is defined outside of the library.  The `react-redux` `connect` HOC will get a store instance from the closest ancestor `<Provider>` when the component is actually rendered.

The problem that you are experiencing is due to mismatched versions of `react-redux` between your library and your app.  The version-`5.0.7` `connect` HOC in your library cannot find a context provider because it is not "seeing" the version-`7.2.4` `Provider` in your app.

I changed the `package.json` in your root folder such that the `redux` and `react-redux` versions match those in the library and everything works!

[Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-fa5m5q?file=package.json)

I would recommend that you upgrade the library version rather than downgrade the app version, but I didn't want to have to re-compile the library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you mentioned, it worked when I downgraded react-redux to 5.0.7. But when I upgraded both the library and app versions to 7.2.4, it was not working. And I have upgraded both library and app to 7.2.4 in my Stackblitz link posted in the question.