# Using Rollup to bundle my lib using RTKQ results in the error:

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rollupjs, rtk-query

The error in question is `could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>`.

I first describe particulars about the library.
Afterwards I describe the environment in which it is run and the error in more detail.

**The lib**

The lib in question is just a collection of api calls governed by RTKQ.
The apiSlice is exported and can then be used by consumer packages to add it to their store.

I must note that this DID work in the past when the collection of API calls was just another file in the same repo, before I (tried) to move it into it's own and make a lib out of it.
It even still worked in the very early versions of the lib, when I just ... didn't bundle it at all, releasing the bare source code as a package.
It only now stopped working after I tried to do it the proper way.

Its rollup config looks like so:

```js
const resolve = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve');
const commonjs = require('@rollup/plugin-commonjs');
const peerDepsExternal = require('rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external');
const babel = require('@rollup/plugin-babel');

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  external: [/@babel\/runtime/],
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'es',
      sourcemap: true,
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      babelHelpers: 'runtime',
    }),
    commonjs({ 
    // the @rollup/plugin-babel readme insists that this should be placed before babel runs; 
    // but this never worked and in all examples I found this was the way it is here. 
      strictRequires: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

Its package.json looks like so:

```json
{
  "name": "some-name",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "main": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.6",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.6.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0",
    "luxon": "^3.1.0",
    "np": "^7.6.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "reactjs-localstorage": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix .",
    "prepare": "npm run co:login",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build && np --no-publish --no-yarn --no-cleanup",
    "build": "rollup --config",
    "start": "webpack serve",
    "devBuild": "webpack --mode=development",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet\""
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^24.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.5.12",
    "rollup": "^3.7.5",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

Its .babelrc file

```json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

I exports it's api slice created with RTKQ's createApi() and also all defined endpoints.

**The consumer**

The current sole consumer is a component lib which uses storybook for testing.

Here is part of it's preview.js

```js
import {
  createTheme,
  CssBaseline,
  responsiveFontSizes,
  ThemeProvider,
} from '@mui/material';
import { SnackbarProvider } from 'notistack';

import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { apiSlice} from '@my_company/the_lib_with_the_error'; // that's the lib
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import { initialize as initializeMSW, mswDecorator } from 'msw-storybook-addon';
import { ConfirmProvider } from 'material-ui-confirm';

// test store
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
  devTools: { trace: true },
});


let theme = createTheme({/** long theming code */});
theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);

initializeMSW({ waitUntilReady: false });


// I have also incorporated the suggestions of Linda Paiste's answer. 
// Sadly, they had no effect. 
const SetupApi = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(timumApiSlice.util.resetApiState());
  }, [dispatch]);
  
  return null;
}

const stdLayout = (Story) => {
  store.dispatch(timumApiSlice.util.resetApiState());

  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <SnackbarProvider
            maxSnack={3}
            autoHideDuration={3000}
            anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom' }}
          >
            <ConfirmProvider>
              <>
                <CssBaseline />
                <SetupApi />
                <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
                  <Story />
                </MemoryRouter>
              </>
            </ConfirmProvider>
          </SnackbarProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

Has anyone any ideas?

**Edit 1**

- clarified how my setup is.
- restructured the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to figure it out.

First, I didn't set react-redux and @redux/redux-toolkit as peerDependencies.
Instead they were handled as normal dependencies. This led to rollup bundling them into the package.
The component lib itself declared react-redux and @redux/redux-toolkit as dependencies.
I believe that this caused the apiSlice to be created using the redux of the lib but the context was set by the redux of the component lib.
(But this is only an assumptions and may be wrong. Please correct me if so.)

Second, for basically the same reason, I did the same for react and react-dom.

Comment: It's okay if the redux context is set by a different package than the consumer, but **the versions must match**.  I recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74783392/how-to-use-the-redux-store-inside-the-library-module/74882864#74882864) where their problem was having mismatched `react-redux` version numbers between the library and the client/app.

Comment: But how do I synchronise that across libraries reliably? Assume I have a dependency like 
`"react": "^18.0.0"``. Both the consumer and my library have the dependecy declared in this exact way in thier respective package.json files. Now my library was last released with 18.0.2 but the current version the  consumer is using is 18.0.3.
The only solution I see is to lock the consumer to version 18.0.2. 
It also requires the consumer to know that they have to use this version. 
Is there some better way to achieve synchronisation which I just do not see?

Answer (score 0):

The `Provider` should be outside of all `dispatch` calls, not in the same component.  You are getting around this by using `store.dispatch` instead of `useDispatch`, but a better approach would be to move that call into a sub-component which is rendered inside of the `Provider`.  Like this:

```
const SetupApi = () => {
    // It's okay to use the useDispatch hook here, because this component is rendered
    // inside of the Provider.
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // Move the side-effects into a useEffect
    useEffect(() => {
        // I'm not sure that this is really needed though?  Isn't your store empty?
        dispatch(timumApiSlice.util.resetApiState());

        window.timumApiSlice = timumApiSlice;
        
    }, [dispatch]);
    
    return null;
}

const stdLayout = (Story) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <SnackbarProvider
                    maxSnack={3}
                    autoHideDuration={3000}
                    anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom' }}
                >
                    <ConfirmProvider>
                        <CssBaseline />
                        <SetupApi/>
                        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
                            <Story />
                        </MemoryRouter>
                    </ConfirmProvider>
                </SnackbarProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

I also moved the Redux `<Provider>` outside of your other providers just in case those components are using Redux data.

I can't guarantee that this alone will fix your issues because I don't fully understand your setup.

You must make sure that your `store` variable contains both the middleware and the reducer from your `timumApiSlice` API object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Sadly, they had no effect. I have restructured the answer and added a bit more info about my setup. I hope this makes it clearer?